# Как создать документ (страницу) для печати?

Tags: c#, print, .net, печать

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема. Мне нужно программно создать страницу для печати. На странице будет 4 одинаковых прямоугольника, в каждом из которых будут какие-то данные о каком-то человеке. Каким образом мне это лучше организовать? Создавать изображение, и на него уже программно выводит информацию или еще каким-то образом? И как учесть нормальное расположение и размер шрифтов и т.п. Просто впервые сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сгенерировать PDF-документ и отобразить его с помощью AcroPDFLib. Там у контрола есть метод для вывода на печать.

Comment: спасибо, я нашел уже решение(не понимаю, почему сразу не додумался), сверстать шаблон в HTML и в него уже все вставлять по ключам.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я просто создаю аналогичную страницу с отключенными стилями (лишними) и без графики. Не вижу смысла что-то мудрить. Из стилей, только какой-то стандартный шрифт и размер.

Comment: каким образом создаете страницу? просто я даже не представляю как это сделать и что использовать

Comment: Ну, у вас же есть страница, где выводится информация для пользователя? Как-то на этой странице генерируется контент. Вот создайте страницу, на которой так же генерируется этот контент, только из стилей подключите шрифт, его размер, размеры для ваших "4 одинаковых прямоугольника", рамку для них если надо. Вот и всё

Comment: у меня еще ничего не генерируется, я пытаюсь понять, как мне это лучше селать